# Get value of multi-dimensional array when path to key is a list

Tags: javascript

```
var a = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: {
        four: 4,
        five: 5,
    },
};
var c = ['three', 'four'];
```

`c` can have `n` values.
`a` is an object containing a lot of data.

I have `c` configured with what particular entry I need to get from `a`.

**I need to get the value `a['three']['four']`.**

I can do it with`if (c.length == 1 or 2 or 3)` and it works but it's not the best way to do it I presume. 
I have also tried `a[c]` but it returns `undefined`.

I have been googleing for an alternative solution all day but I can't seem to find anything.
I guess is not very common problem.

Comment: First of all `c` is an array, `a` is an object. Secondly, where is the problem? you did not ask anything.

Comment: *I am using if c.length == 1 or 2 or 3 right now and it works but it's not the best way to do it...* To do what?

Comment: `value = c.reduce(function(o,x) { return o[x] }, a)`

Comment: var ac = a[c[0]][c[1]]; try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the number of keys held in the `c` array are unknown.

I like the `.reduce()` solution given in the comments, but here's a verbose walk-through of what needs to take place so that you understand.

```
// Your initial data
var a = {one: 1, two: 2, three: {four: 4, five: 5}};
var c = ['three', 'four'];

// New variable to store the result. We start it off with the `a` object
var result = a;

// Loop the property names
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    // Grab the property at the current array index
    var key = c[i];

    // Get the value using the key and the current `result` object
    var new_obj = result[key];

    // Overwrite the current `result` object with the new value we got from the key
    result = new_obj;

    // Break the loop if we ran out of data
    if (result == null)
        break;
}
```

---

So basically we just loop the keys, and in each iteration grab a value from the current object, and overwrite the current object with the new value.

When the loop is done, hopefully we've traversed to the point we intended.

---

A less verbose version could look like this:

```
var result = a;

for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    result = result[c[i]];

    if (result == null)
        break;
}
```

Comment: sorry, but thg435 was first

Comment: @tntu: I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: thg435 posted 3 hours ago: value = c.reduce(function(o,x) { return o[x] }, a)

Comment: I will give him some time to post his answer. If that does not happen eventually I will pick yours.

Comment: @tntu: Oh, okay. Doesn't matter to me at all, and probably doesn't matter to thg435 either. My only purpose was to explain the concept. Tell you what, I'll make this a wiki.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It was truly helpful to understand the concept. Making this a wiki is a good idea, as it is not something very common encountered but it is still something people will want to find easily.